Unmet dependencies when attempting to install libncurses5-dev
I'm attempting to install libncurses5-dev. When doing so, I get a strange error saying I have unmet dependencies:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed
                   Depends: libncurses5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed
                   Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

When attempting to manually install all of the dependencies, most install fine, until I attempt to install libtinfo-dev, which has its own dependency that gives the exact same error.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtinfo-dev: Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed.

When attempting to install this dependency manually, it shows me I have a version of it. However, when trying to install the specific version given, it cannot be found.
I am relatively new to all of this, so there may be something I am missing.

deb packages are built for a specific release, and you've not told us yours.  The only thing clear is your package versions are all EOL or EOSS which is likely related; but starting point is what are you running (also libncurses5 was replaced with libncurses6 so your issue is release specific).
